# I can not access it from any list element method (Invalid argument (index): "2") in Angular dart

Tags: angular-dart

```
@Component(
  selector: 'my-app',   
  template: '''  <div> <button (click)="getItemName(2)"> get</button> </div>    ''',
) 
class ListComponent {  //...
  List<Product> listProducts;

  void getItemName(int id) {
    print(listProducts[id].name); // <- invalid argumant (index) : "2"
  } 
}
```

> html_dart2js.dart:3558 EXCEPTION: Invalid argument (index): "0"
>   STACKTRACE:  Invalid argument (index): "0"
>       at Object.wrapException (http://127.0.0.1:8092/main.dart.js:4242:17)
>       at Interceptor.$index (http://127.0.0.1:8092/main.dart.js:1082:19)
>       at Object.J.$index$asx (http://127.0.0.1:8092/main.dart.js:102985:43)
>       at GroupsComponent.add$1 (http://127.0.0.1:8092/main.dart.js:45152:46)
>       at Object.J.add$1$ax (http://127.0.0.1:8092/main.dart.js:103054:42)
>       at ViewGroupsComponent0.dart.ViewGroupsComponent0._handle_click_131_0$1

**where do i make mistakes thanks**

Comment: What does it print if you add `print('listProducts.length ${listProducts.length}');` before the line with the error?

Comment: print('listProducts.length ${listProducts.length}');
List size 5

Comment: what does `print('is num: ${id is num}');` print?

Comment: as you said, parametrem num is not the type,
thanks you very much Günter,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The index parameter needs to be an integer value, not a string.